# Why not use the anchor boxes for the grid based search to detect objects directly in YOLO algorithm?

Tags: yolo

The YOLO algorithm does a grid search based on the grid squares (I'm not sure if they ALWAYS are squares) and when an object is detected in one of the squares, check for the maximum 'Intersection over Union' with one of the anchor boxes and then draw the boundary around the object.

My question is, is computational inefficiency the sole reason why we don't simply run these anchor boxes instead of first running the squares around and then checking with the anchor boxes? I am just starting out with this, so I haven't implemented anything of yet. I don't know how costly that inefficiency will be.

Also, why the name 'You Only Look Once'? Is it just the researchers having a fun time or does it have a reason?